# python: untar then tar

Tags: python, tarfile

When I run the following, I'd expect the infile and outfile to be the same, but they are not on the files I've tested.  Sizes are slightly different and tar tvf shows I've gained a trailing / on dirs

I'm running on windows and python 2.7.9

What am I doing wrong?

```
import tarfile
import io

fn = 'infile.tar'
outf = 'outfile.tar'

with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()  # read the rest

tf = tarfile.open(fileobj=io.BytesIO(data))

iofile = io.BytesIO()
out = tarfile.open(fileobj=iofile, mode='w')

for item in tf.getmembers():
    if item.isfile():
        f = tf.extractfile(item)
        contents = f.read()
        out.addfile(item, io.BytesIO(contents))
        print('{}: {}'.format(item.name, len(contents)))
    elif item.isdir():
        t = item
        out.addfile(t)
        print('{}: **isdir**'.format(item.name))
    else:
        print('{}: **unknown**'.format(item.name))
out.close()

contents = iofile.getvalue()
with open(outf, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(contents)
```

EDIT: partial example:
original

```
-rw------- 1000/1000      1214 1969-12-31 19:00 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/_manifest
-rw-r--r-- 1000/1000  37044320 2015-03-12 23:40 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/a/base.apk
drwxrwx--x 10152/10152       0 2015-01-11 10:15 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/r/app_webview
drwx------ 10152/10152       0 2015-01-11 10:15 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/r/app_webview/Cache
-rw------- 10152/10152     844 2015-01-11 10:15 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/r/app_webview/Cache/213163dd3446f027_0
```

changed:

```
-rw------- 1000/1000      1214 1969-12-31 19:00 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/_manifest
-rw-r--r-- 1000/1000  37044320 2015-03-12 23:40 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/a/base.apk
drwxrwx--x 10152/10152       0 2015-01-11 10:15 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/r/app_webview/
drwx------ 10152/10152       0 2015-01-11 10:15 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/r/app_webview/Cache/
-rw------- 10152/10152     844 2015-01-11 10:15 apps/com.antutu.ABenchMark/r/app_webview/Cache/213163dd3446f027_0
```

I've been testing on android backup files, which are too big to post.

Comment: Show us some sample pathname differences, and list a few files with sizes that differ

Comment: @smci See Q for some pathname differences. The tar files are different sizes, e.g., 37,508,096 to 37,509,120.